# Differential amplifier inaccuracy resistors exercise to calculate CMRR

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, differential-amplifier, tolerance

The common mode gain for a differential amplifier in the general case is:

$${V_o \over V_c }={ R_1R_4-R_2R_3 \over R_1(R_3 + R_4) }\tag{1}$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQGO17.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose the resistances have relative inaccuracy of \$\,\varepsilon_i(i=1\,\text{to 4})\$ so  \$R_i=R_i^*(\varepsilon+1)\$ where \$R_i^*\$ is the nominal value of \$R_i\$.

Also suppose that \$\varepsilon_i\lt\lt1\$ and,

$$\tag{2}R_1^* = R_3^*\,\text{and}\,R_2^*=R_4^*\qquad\text{(condition for differential amplifier)}$$

Then,
$$\tag{3}A_c={ R_1R_4-R_2R_3 \over R_1(R_3 + R_4) }\approx{R_2^* \over R_1^*+R_2^*}(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_4-\varepsilon_2-\varepsilon_3)$$

But I can't find this value algebraically.

This is important because the worst case CMRR is:

$$\tag{4}CMRR={A_d \over A_c}={1+R_2/R_1\over\mid\varepsilon_1\mid+\mid\varepsilon_2\mid+\mid\varepsilon_3\mid+\mid\varepsilon_4\mid}.$$

Comment: maybe I should ask this question in the mathematics

Comment: What are you asking here? The expression for \$A_c\$ with your substitutions (i.e., just a bit of algebra), or the expression for the error in the common mode gain with respect to the errors in the resistor values? The former is just $$A_c\approx{R_2^*(\varepsilon_1-\varepsilon_2-\varepsilon_3+\varepsilon_4)\over(R_3+R_4)(1+\varepsilon_1)}$$ if we assume the error products \$\varepsilon_2\varepsilon_3\$ and \$\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_4\$ are negligible. (Note that those are the real \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ in the denominator, not the nominal values.)

Comment: Thank you very much for having done the math too. I want to algebraically come to the given value. At first I didn't see that the error products are indeed negligible. So now my numerator is the same as in the penultimate equation.  
What's different are the denominators, (R3+R4)(1+ε1) cannot be R∗1+R∗2 right? Only if you neglect all the errors in the denominator. If you think this is correct, can you explain why? Thank you again

Comment: I see. I don't know, sorry. Where does your given expression come from? Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: http://www.ee.mut.ac.th/home/suriya/ebooks/Electronic%20Instrumentation.PDF page 188

Comment: I'm not sure it's correct. No derivation is shown, and it doesn't seem to follow from the definitions given. Maybe with some additional assumptions it would, but apart from neglecting the error products all other simplifications seem questionable. You can of course calculate the worst-case CMRR for yourself without using any approximations, and then simplify it to the extent that you think justifiable. That's what I'd do.

Comment: I have been thinking about this more and I cannot see how the expression for the worst-case CMRR can come from the other given expressions. This final result is not the right expression for the CMRR, and the \$\varepsilon_i\$'s are up until this point stated not to be tolerances but *actual errors* that could take any value inside the tolerance band. Now, if you suddenly decide to reinterpret \$\varepsilon_i\$ as meaning a tolerance rather than an error in the final expression, then yes, it is correct (AFAICT). This may be the essential source of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case CMRR is appropriate to the expression you gave, since the absolute values of the error or tolerance gives the maximum common mode gain. And Differential gain is as usual equal to R2/R1